# Wii U Toolchain WiFi and more

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja, wii, wii-u

I'm trying to code a little homebrew app that either opens the system settings **(he can't open the Wii U menu without it feezing)**, since he needs that to unbrick his Wii U or enable Internet by changing the configuration so it fits his WiFi credentials from now, not like 10 years ago. I have tried everything, some code is even written by Copilot and ChatGPT and I tried to fix it but no luck. Since the **[Wii U Toolchain (wut) from devkitpro](https://github.com/devkitPro/wut/tree/master)** has little to no [documentation](https://wut.devkitpro.org/), so I came here. I know my code is messy and stuff but I really hope you guys can help me here.

***main.cpp:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <coreinit/screen.h>
#include <vpad/input.h>
#include <wut.h>
#include <whb/proc.h>
#include <whb/log.h>
#include <whb/log_console.h>
#include <sysapp/launch.h>
#include <nn/ac.h>




int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Initialisiere alles
    WHBProcInit();
    VPADInit();
    OSScreenInit();
    WHBLogConsoleInit();
    nn::ac::Initialize();

    while (WHBProcIsRunning()) {
        VPADStatus vpad;
        VPADRead(VPAD_CHAN_0, &vpad, 1, NULL);
        OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0x000000FF);
        OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_TV, 0x000000FF);
        OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 0, "Drücke A für Systemeinstellungen");
        OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 0, "Drücke A für Systemeinstellungen");
        OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
        OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);
        OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 20, "Drücke Y für Intaned");
        OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 20, "Drücke Y für Intaned");
        OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
        OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);

        if (vpad.trigger & VPAD_BUTTON_A) {
            uint64_t titleid = 0x0005001010047200;
            SYSLaunchTitle(titleid);
        }
        
        if (vpad.trigger & VPAD_BUTTON_Y) {
            OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0x000000FF);
            OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_TV, 0x000000FF);
            OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 20, "Der Y-Knopf wurde gedrückt!");
            OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 20, "Der Y-Knopf wurde gedrückt!");
            OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
            OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);
            nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(1500000000))
            nn::ac::ConfigIdNum config;
            nn::ac::GetStartupIdNum(&config);
            nn::ac::Details details;
            nn::ac::GetDetails(config, &details);
            OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0x000000FF);
            OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_TV, 0x000000FF);
            OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 0, "Drücke Y für die Netzwerkdetails");
            OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 0, "Drücke Y für die Netzwerkdetails");
            OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
            OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);
            if(vpad.trigger & VPAD_BUTTON_Y){
                char buffer[1024];
                snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "IP Address: %s, SSID: %s, Gateway: %s", 
                details.ip_address, details.ssid, details.gateway);
                const char* str = buffer;
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 20, str);
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 20, str);
            }
            nn::ac::ConnectAsync(config);


            while (nn::ac::GetStatus() != nn::ac::Status_Connecting) {
                nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(5000000000));
            }

            if (nn::ac::GetStatus() == nn::ac::Status_Connected) {
                OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0x000000FF);
                OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_TV, 0x000000FF);
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 0, "WLAN ist am start");
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 0, "WLAN ist am start");
                OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
                OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);
            } else {
                OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0x000000FF);
                OSScreenClearBufferEx(SCREEN_TV, 0x000000FF);
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_DRC, 0, 0, "WLAN sagt nahhh");
                OSScreenPutFontEx(SCREEN_TV, 0, 0, "WLAN sagt nahhh");
                OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_DRC);
                OSScreenFlipBuffersEx(SCREEN_TV);
            }
               }
    }

    WHBLogConsoleFree();
    WHBProcShutdown();
    OSScreenShutdown();
    VPADShutdown();
    nn::ac::Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using following commands to compile it on the devkitpro msys2:

`cmake -B build -S . -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/devkitpro/cmake/WiiU.cmake`

`ninja -C build`

If you're wondering what errors I have when compiling. I'm happy to provide:

```
D:/Wii U/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:48:17: error: 'nn::os' has not been declared
   48 |             nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(1500000000))
      |                 ^~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:48:37: error: 'nn::TimeSpan' has not been declared
   48 |             nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(1500000000))
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:50:21: error: 'GetStartupIdNum' is not a member of 'nn::ac'; did you mean 'GetStartupId'?
   50 |             nn::ac::GetStartupIdNum(&config);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     GetStartupId
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:50:38: error: 'config' was not declared in this scope
   50 |             nn::ac::GetStartupIdNum(&config);
      |                                      ^~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:51:21: error: 'Details' is not a member of 'nn::ac'; did you mean 'detail'?
   51 |             nn::ac::Details details;
      |                     ^~~~~~~
      |                     detail
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:52:21: error: 'GetDetails' is not a member of 'nn::ac'
   52 |             nn::ac::GetDetails(config, &details);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:52:41: error: 'details' was not declared in this scope
   52 |             nn::ac::GetDetails(config, &details);
      |                                         ^~~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:70:28: error: 'GetStatus' is not a member of 'nn::ac'; did you mean 'GetStartupId'?
   70 |             while (nn::ac::GetStatus() != nn::ac::Status_Connecting) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
      |                            GetStartupId
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:70:51: error: 'Status_Connecting' is not a member of 'nn::ac'
   70 |             while (nn::ac::GetStatus() != nn::ac::Status_Connecting) {
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:71:21: error: 'nn::os' has not been declared
   71 |                 nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(5000000000));
      |                     ^~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:71:41: error: 'nn::TimeSpan' has not been declared
   71 |                 nn::os::SleepThread(nn::TimeSpan::FromNanoSeconds(5000000000));
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:74:25: error: 'GetStatus' is not a member of 'nn::ac'; did you mean 'GetStartupId'?
   74 |             if (nn::ac::GetStatus() == nn::ac::Status_Connected) {
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~
      |                         GetStartupId
D:/Wii U/main.cpp:74:48: error: 'Status_Connected' is not a member of 'nn::ac'
   74 |             if (nn::ac::GetStatus() == nn::ac::Status_Connected) {
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm trying to **either:**

Open the system settings

or

Alter the WiFi configuration so the Wii U can connect to wifi

using the [Wii U toolchain (wut) of devkitpro](https://github.com/devkitPro/wut/tree/master)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).